# InDesign GREP find between

Tags: regex, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

In InDesign's GREP search I'm trying to get parts of a text field which was filled with a CSV (file using `#` as delimiter). The reason I want to grep the different parts is to give each a different character style.

The Textfield content looks like this:

```
Alpha#60x50cm#Acryl
Beta#2013#50x40cm#Öl
Gamma#2013#50x40cm#Holz
…
```

Using

```
^[^#]+
```

would work fine to get the first part of each line, (which is delimited by the first hashtag)

[image]

How would Grep pattern look like to get:

- everything between hashtag 1 and 2,
- everything between hashtag 2 and 3,
- everything after hashtag 3?

In every line.

Comment: Can you say what must happen when you *find* these items? If this is for while working in the UI, GREP is your best shot. However, if this is to work inside a script, there are other -- easier! -- options than a complicated GREP.

Comment: Which grep you mean? try this `(?<=#)[^#\n]*(?=#|$)` regex.

Comment: Hi Jongware, I want to assign different character style to each part. With the grep I posted I get every character until the first hashtag (in every line) with this I could attach f.e. a character style called "headline". Next I want format every character between first and secong hashtag with cahracter style "subtitle". that´s why I need the greps

Comment: @tBook: to make sure an earlier entrant in the discussion thread notices your comment, you can "ping" them with an `@` character before his/her name. Using `@jongware` will indicate in the top bar that I have a message. The SO interface helps with auto-completing names from the current discussion.

Comment: @Jongware thanks did not knew that.

Comment: It's still basically the same question. I tested my answer and it does what you seem to be asking, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jongware Sorry it seems I did not recognize your answer when commenting. It works perfectly. -Thank you very much- The JS solution is a good hint as I code it, seems I have to dive more into Indesign Scripting ;)

Comment: As you can see it also works nicely using GREP styles. The interface between ID's own formatted text and Javascript is ... clunky. It *can* be very efficient, but it requires quite a firm grasp of JS. Should you try and get to a point where you *almost* got it working, don't hesitate to post another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the InDesign UI, you can

1. search for `^[^#]+` to match the contents of the first field;
2. search for `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#[^#]*#[^#]*$)` to match the contents of the second field;
3. search for `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#[^#]+$)` to match the contents of the third field;
4. finally, search for `(?<=#)[^#]+$` to match the contents of the fourth field.

This relies on all lines having *exactly* four fields (and thus 3 `#`), and will match only the text in between two `#` markers. Here is an image showing the result with these four applied as GREP styles:

[image: grep styles to highlite fields]

As you can see, the applied attributes overlap nowhere, so everything is only marked once.

Another way is to use Javascript. All of the lines can be split on the `#` character (the command is called `split`), and that returns an array of the text in between. However, this converts the text into a plain Javascript string, and it takes some trickery to translate the result "back" to native formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-P` parameter with grep.

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=#)[^#]*(?=#|$)' file
,2013
60x50cm
Acryl
2013
50x40cm
Öl
2013
50x40cm
Holz
```

To change the above command's output as three columns per line.

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=#)[^#]*(?=#|$)' file | paste - - -
,2013   60x50cm Acryl
2013    50x40cm Öl
2013    50x40cm Holz
```

Comment: or `grep -oP '(?<=#)[^#\n]*(?=#|$)' file`